# Update column of a dataframe when key matches from another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.

[image]

For all rows in df1, find the corresponding row in df2 (through matching key) and update the final column in df2 to 1.
How shall I proceed in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Remove column `final`, use left join with `indicator` parameter, so is possible create `1,0` column by mapping `True, False` by compare `both`:

```
df = df2.drop('final', axis=1).merge(df1, how='left', indicator='final')
df['final'] = df['final'].eq('both').astype(int)
```